# Configuring the number of buffers saved by ido, using ido-use-virtual-buffers?

Tags: ido, desktop

I really love the ability to quickly navigate to files opened in old editing sessions that `desktop` provides.  However, there are a few things I don't like about it so I'd like to stop using it if possible, but I'm not quite there yet.

What I don't like about `desktop`:  Note neither of these would be a problem if buffers were merely easily re-openable, rather than immediately re-opened (as `desktop-change-dir` does):

- Slow startup with large numbers of buffers
- A tendency to make it harder to diagnose problems in my emacs configuration, because of side-effects from opening buffers

What I'm trying to use instead of `desktop`:

- `ido-use-virtual-buffers`: This `ido` feature keeps a list of closed buffers.  When using ido to switch buffer, the closed buffers show up too (with a different face and different prioritization).
- `saveplace` to save `point` (cursor position) in buffers
- `savehist` to save minibuffer history

This is all great, except that `ido` is only saving a small number of buffers for me in `ido.last`.  How can I have several hundred buffers saved by `ido` across emacs restart, and have them saved whether they are closed ('virtual') or not?

<s>Customizing `ido-max-work-file-list` doesn't seem to have any effect for me.</s> -- actually it does, see answer

I'm aware of `projectile` and use that too, but this is a bit different.  I'm also aware of `recentf`, but I'd prefer to stick with `ido-use-virtual-buffers`, because aside from lack of persistence across emacs sessions it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ido gets its file history from multiple places:

If `ido-use-virtual-buffers` is enabled, ido uses `recentf` to save buffer history.  At history save time (e.g. on emacs shutdown), `recentf-files` may include both virtual (closed) and non-virtual buffers, so `recentf-save-list` will save both to file `~/.emacs.d/recentf`.  When emacs is started again later on, they will all become ido virtual buffers.

ido also has "work directory" and "work file" features.  These are used via `ido-next-work-directory` and `ido-prev-work-directory` (M-n / M-p or M-down / M-up), and by `ido-next-work-file` and `ido-prev-work-file` (C-M-o / C-o).  `ido-max-work-file-list` controls the number of work files stored in `ido-work-file-list` (and similarly `ido-max-work-directory-list` controls `ido-work-directory-list`).  These lists are persisted to file `~/.emacs.d/ido.last` by `ido-save-history`.

The reason that I was seeing files not saved in `ido.last` is that buffers are not added to `ido-work-file-list` unless they are visited **using `ido`**.  They are not added to that list if they are visited using `dired`.  So I've added this to my init files so that regardless of how a file is opened, it gets added to the list:

```
(defun my/add-to-ido-work-file-list ()
    (ido-record-work-file (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
    (ido-record-work-directory (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my/add-to-ido-work-file-list)
```

Comment: I've been using this setup with `recentf`, `ido-virtual-buffers`, `saveplace` and `savehist` for a while now and I'm finding it really great.  No more waiting for `desktop-mode` to load my bloated desktop file with hundreds of buffers!